# How to get name/export index of a symbol at a specific address (GetProcAddress inverse)

Tags: file, export, symbols, portable-executable

Suppose I have a DLL that exports some functions and I know an address within that DLL. *If* that address refers to an location within such a function, *then*, assuming the export table is sorted by function entry, the following would find the index of this function in the export table:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dosHeader;
dosHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)m_handle;
unsigned int count;

if(dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{return __MODULE_ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND;}

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* ntHeaders = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)(((BYTE*)dosHeader) + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

if(ntHeaders->Signature != 0x00004550)
    {return __MODULE_ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND;}

IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER* optionalHeader = &ntHeaders->OptionalHeader;
if(optionalHeader->NumberOfRvaAndSizes<IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT)
    {return __MODULE_ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND;}

if(optionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].Size==0)
    {return __MODULE_ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND;}

IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY* dataDirectory = &optionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY* Exp;
Exp = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)((DWORD)dosHeader + dataDirectory->VirtualAddress);

ULONG* addressoffunctions=(ULONG*)((BYTE*) m_handle + Exp->AddressOfFunctions);

if(Exp->NumberOfNames==1)
{
    if(addressoffunctions[0] + (BYTE*)m_handle < address)
        {return 0;}
    return __MODULE_ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND;
    }

for(count = 1; count < Exp->NumberOfNames; count++)
    {
    if(addressoffunctions[count-1] + (BYTE*)m_handle >= address
    && addressoffunctions[count] + (BYTE*)m_handle < address)
        {return count-1;}
    }
```

, but how do I assert that the address really refers to an location within an exported function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common case, you can't. You should disassemble whole function instructions graph to get addresses of all its instructions.

In some trivial cases, you can search for `ret` instruction, but it's not reliable.

If you can perform static analysis, you can use IDA to get function boundaries.